# Why do SIS and Interpol systems only consider names/DOBs in travel documents, and not document numbers?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, lost-documents

Lost an identity card in 2018 and subsequently got a new one. The old one of course got blocked.

However, when using my new one, an alert pops up referring to the old one, which border control occasionally reacts to (they then normally more or less tell me about it if we have a common language, but it could be the reason for me being held for an hour in Milan recently, under the false pretext of me allegedly not being allowed into Italy passport-free if arriving directly from Ukraine).

According to a specialist at the Swedish police, it's because the systems recognise my name and date of birth, but don't take into consideration the new document number.

Now, I imagine if someone were to find my old ID and copy and sell to an illegal immigrant, they would either copy all the data exactly, or alter all the data.

In what case would they alter the document number but leave the other data intact?

What it boils down to is: why would using my current ID trigger an alert due to my old one?

I don't know if using a passport would have the same effect - I'll reply and ask that after hopefully getting feedback from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you lost your ID and it’s possible that shady people have learned that a certain person (you) exists and if they were to impersonate someone, they might as well use a real person. However, they’re aware that you’ll apply for a new document and this particular one would become invalid. Thus they could have forged a document with your data but with a fake number and sent someone into Milan from Ukraine for more shady things. Until careful inspection of your document confirms it’s genuine, this hypothetical situation is indistinguishable from what actually happened, thus investigation is warranted.

Answer (score 1):

The document number is checked too. Sometimes an ID card number is linked to a Social Security number therefore the replacement card will have the same number as the lost/stolen card. In those instances the Officer will consider the date of issue of the replacement card to ensure it post dates the reported loss/theft. Sometimes a national ID card will have the same alpha/numeric sequence as another nation's passports, so the Officer will consider the type of document reported lost/stolen and the document being presented. In addition the Officer will question the document holder to allay or confirm suspicions.

Comment: Our IDs have individual document numbers

Comment: Some people get stopped repeatedly for having a number which is like the number of someone who should be stopped, with one easily adjustable number changed, like having an 8 where the other has a 3. The only way out is getting a new passport or ID card.

Comment: @Willeke Oh OK, good to know for the future